# A better way to do over 150 country recodes?

Tags: r, if-statement, indexing, dplyr, recode

I'm trying to recode a variable consisting of the recognised countries into regions that I am specifying. I've tried to do multiple `if_else` statements using `dplyr` to recode country variable into regions, but it is getting ridiculously long.

I would like to use *for* loop to loop through several countries in a vector and change the value to something new, in the example below I'd like to change the values in `df$country` that match `i` and change it to `"Europe"`.  This is the code I've developed, which doesn't seem to want to work.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
df <- data.frame(country =c("Netherlands", "US", "Canada", "Frace", "Italy"),
       ID=1:100)
i <- c("Netherlands", "France", "Italy")
n <- length(i)

for (i in n){
df$country[(df$country == i)] <- "Europe"
}
```

I'm getting several different errors depending on how I change the formatting.  It seems that nothing will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the 'country' is `factor`, we can assign the `levels` of the 'country' that are `%in%` 'i' to 'Europe' instead of using a `for` loop

```
levels(df$country)[levels(df$country) %in% i] <- "Europe"
```

Comment: Wow, this seems to work pretty perfectly.  If I understand it correctly, you're code is:
1. calling for the levels of df$country;
2. indexing the factor levels that match i;
3. changing matches to "Europe".
Can you explain the %in% pipe? I've looked several times for it online but can't find a good overview.

Comment: @elliot If there are multiple elements to match, you can use `%in%` to return a logical vector.  `levels(df$country) %in% i` returns a logical vector i.e. TRUE/FALSE, we subset the `levels(df$country)` based on that logical vector and assign it to 'Europe'

Comment: thanks for this! I've been trying to overcome this issue for months now.  Bless you.

Comment: Now that the issue is solved it no longer matters but there's something very wrong with `for (i in n)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas  Yes, 1) 'i' is a character vector 2 ) n is scalar

Comment: @akrun I believe the OP meant `for(j in seq_along(i))` then in the loop use `i[j]`. At least it would make sense.

Comment: I solved similar problems by having a reference table, in your case this df would have (1) Country and (2) Region. Then I would merge the reference table with my DF that I was trying to classify. It simplified my coding.